# Post thumbnail outside of loop

Tags: post-thumbnails

I'm trying to show a post thumbnail outside of the loop. The reason for this is that i want the featured image to show inside a custom page template, which will set the header image for the particular page for which the custom page template is set.

I've tried the obvious `the_post_thumbnail();` and as expected, it didn't work. What's the best solution for using the featured image outside of the loop?

The custom page template code i'm working with...

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

    <div class="home-header-image">

    <?php IMAGE WILL GO HERE ?> 

    </div>

    <div class="top_items_container">
        <?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Home Top Content')) :

endif; ?>
    </div><!-- .top_items_container -->

                <div class="entry-content">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                    <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links"><span class="page-links-title">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentythirteen' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>', 'link_before' => '<span>', 'link_after' => '</span>' ) ); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->

                <footer class="entry-meta">
                    <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentythirteen' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
                </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
            </article><!-- #post -->

            <?php comments_template(); ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look into the function single_post_title() in the general-template.php file and you will find following:

```
$_post = get_queried_object();
```

and in that function you also see:

```
$_post->post_title
```

which gives you the title of the page outside of the loop.

Now to get the Featured Image you simply do the following

```
$_post = get_queried_object(); <br>echo get_the_post_thumbnail($_post->ID);
```

Comment: `get_the_post_thumbnail` outputs HTML. Did you mean `get_the_post_thumbnail_url`

Answer (score 1):

[`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) will accept a post ID as the first parameter. From the Codex:

```
<?php $pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => 1)); ?> 
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($pages as $page): ?>
        <li>
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>
            <h1><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></h1>
            <?php echo $page->post_content; ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Without seeing more context I don't think I can do better than that broad outline and generic example.

If your thumbnail is attached to the page assigned to this template, then the following should do it:

```
// global $post; // maybe but probably not
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID);
```

`$post` will be the current post object and it is set before the Loop begins to the first post in the Loop. On a single page there is only one post so `$post` should be one you want.

Comment: I have updated the main question to include the code i'm currently working with.

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in the source of [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_the_post_thumbnail/), per default it relies on `get_the_ID()` if no ID/1st-argument was provided. And [`get_the_ID()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_the_id/) relies on `get_post()` which relies on the global `$post` object filled by [`setup_postdata()`](http://queryposts.com/function/setup_postdata/) which gets filled by global `$wp_query`/the current `WP_Query` object.

So the obvious thing to do is simply provide the `ID` of the post that is the *main* post for this attachment. In other words the first post this attachment got assigned to. Not very convenient, I know.

There's another public API function that allows fetching the attachment by its ID directly:

```
wp_get_attachment_image( $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $icon, $attr );
```

Now this will return the HTML for the attachment. If you just want the plain data, go with [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_get_attachment_image_src/)

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size = 'thumbnail', $icon = false )
```

which returns an array (url, width, height), or false, if no image is available.

To get the src only, do the following:

```
$attachmentArray = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'thumbnail', false );

FALSE !== $attachmentArray
    AND print $attachmentArray['url'];
```